# Align text in text view

Tags: android

I have two text view  first one aligns on the left of parent and contains a single 
word. the backgroung color of first is different from second one.The next textview contains
 two lines. I need to display the first line of text to the right of first text view and the second line of text to the bottom of the first text view.

the view is like this 'Date' is the word and rest is the text in second text view.

**Date** This my new car. Thank u all

for your advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use RelativeLayout as a parent and then for second text box use attribute `android:layout_toRightof[first text view]`.

In the first text view, specify `width="wrap_content"` so that single word doesn't fill your parent.

This should work.